# Postfix not working on MacOS Yosemite

Tags: postfix, mac-osx, osx-yosemite

Postfix would not bind to the ipv6 port. Gives an error of:

*** postfix/master[39799]: fatal: bind fe80::1 port 25: Can't assign requested address

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I changed main.cf to bind to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

```
inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1
```

Restarted postfix

```
$ sudo launchctl stop org.postfix.master
$ sudo launchctl start org.postfix.master
```